# Pear installed, but php includes provides errors

Tags: php, windows, windows-server-2008, pear, plesk

I just leased a dedicated windows server with Plesk 10.4 installed. I assumed that php, etc would all be configured and that I could prot my sites over with no isses...

Turns out the default image didn't have pear installed...I believe i need pear so include statements work in php...so I used go-pear.bat to install it...

However, I'm still getting an error when including (you can follow the path to see the file exists)

```
Warning: include(Connections/SamConnection.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\80stunes.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 3

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Connections/SamConnection.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\PEAR;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5;./includes;./pear') in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\80stunes.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 3
```

Any ideas on what I have done wrong?  I can run pear commands from a command prompt when accessing my pleskphp5 directory

Comment: You migh need to add something to your `include_path`

Comment: Mario - what should I include? I'm a total noob to configuring this (was always setup before this on other servers --- this is the first time I've had the issue or trying to set it up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may have [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/open_basedir) enabled.

Comment: Open_basedir is commented out in my php.ini...Should I uncomment it and put the main server site locations (C:\intepub\vhosts as well as the C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5  diretcory)  What impact would open_basedir have?  I'm a noob when it comes to configuring php :)

Comment: check the values via [phpinfo](http://www.php.net/phpinfo)(). If it's disabled, all I can think of is you don't have read permission, but the error message would probably be different I think.

Comment: Thanks!!  Appears Plesk 10 had automatically assigned a open_basedir directory via the domain setup which overrides the default php.ini...Apparently there was a bug in Plek that it didn't like domains starting with numbers and stripped them...I manually overwrote the plesk  open basedir settings and it worked...